# Find a simpler solution to an Olympiad problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, integers

So, I have the following problem:

> Find all $n,m \in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $n + (n+1) + \dots + (n+m) = 100$

My Solution/Attempt :

If we open up the brackets, we get:
$$n + n+1 + \dots + n+m = 100$$
So we are actually adding $m+1$ $n$'s and the first $m$ integers, so we get:
$$\underbrace{n+n+\dots+n}_{m+1} + (1+2+3+\dots+m)=100$$
$$\implies n(m+1) + \frac{m(m+1)}{2} = 100$$
$$\implies (m+1)\left(n+\frac{m}{2}\right) = 100$$
Now, I tried to remove the fraction $\frac{m}{2}$ by multiplying both sides by $2$ and got:
$$(m+1)(2n+m) = 200$$
Now, I can just factor $200$ and the equate the LHS to RHS and solve for $n,m$. But is there a simpler solution to this problem? I believe there is but couldn't find one. Any hint/answer is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like the fastest method to me, this is exactly what I would do.

Comment: This solution (at least the concept behind it) seems fairly optimal to me.  If you prefer you could note that the question is the same as asking to write $200=T_{n+m}-T_{n-1}$  Where $T_i$ denotes the triangular numbers.  But that's really not much of a difference.

Comment: Probably not. Note that the two factors are of different parity, so you need to factor $200=ab$ where one is even and the other odd. That will greatly reduce your cases. Also, $2n+m>m+1.$

Comment: $m+1$ and $m+2n$ have different parity, and $200=8\times25$, you only need to consider how to factor these two 5.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah, I see... Parity affects that, didn't notice that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot@Q9y5

Comment: In a write up, I would skip that first step and just jump to the step $$(n+\cdots+n)+(1+\cdots m)=100,$$ arguing “by commutativity and associativity.”

Comment: @lulu I don't see how I can use triangular numbers for this. Can you please elaborate or write an answer? Thanks

Comment: @Iamaperson Thanks

Comment: @Algebrology no problem, good sol!

Comment: @Iamaperson Thanks again :D

Comment: @Algebrology   We have $T_{n+m}=\frac {(n+m)*(n+m+1)}2$ and $T_{n-1}=\frac {n(n-1)}2$ which quickly resolves to the same equation you wrote.  Like I said, no real advantage to doing it that way....I was just proposing a (slightly) different way of looking at it.

Comment: @lulu Ah ok.. got it... Thanks

Comment: Yet Another Way to evaluate the sum: the sum of the terms in a finite arithmetic progression is equal to the number of terms multipled by their average. This gives immediately $(m+1)\cdot\frac12(2n+m)$. Nothing very clever here, but it saves time in an exam.

Comment: @TonyK Wow, didn't think about it, gonna try it. Thanks

Comment: @Algebrology $(m+1)^2<200 \implies m\le13$

Comment: @Tomita Thanks for that

Comment: Why the downvote :/ ?